# Update class from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update the class plays with the response from my ajax call, but only the specific  instance.

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();

    jQuery(as).ready(function($) {
        $('.ca_podcast_file').each(function(){

            /* cache the container instance in a variable*/
            var $container=$(this);
            /* searching within the container instance for each 
            component insulates multiple instances on page*/
            var $audio= $container.find('audio');

            /*now events will only be bound to this instance*/ 
            $audio.on('playing',function(){
                /* within event callbacks keep searches within the main container element*/                     
                var fileID=$audio.attr('id');
                var data = {file_id: fileID ,security:ChurchAdminAjax.security};

                jQuery.post(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl, { 'action': 'ca_mp3_action','data':   data }, 
                    function(response){

                        $($container,'.plays').html(response);
                    }
                );

            });


        });

    });
});
```

Html markup

```
<div class="ca_podcast_file">
   <h3>Hearing God</h3>
       <p><audio class="sermonmp3" id="54" src="http://www.thegatewaychurch.info/wp-content/uploads/sermons/sermon2013-10-27.mp3" preload="none"/></p>
       <p><a href="http://www.thegatewaychurch.info/wp-content/uploads/sermons/sermon2013-10-27.mp3"  title="Hearing God">Hearing God</a></a> <br/>
       Mike Bollinger prophecies over some people and then helps to get going in hearing for God for ourselves <br/>
      <span style="font-size:smaller">The Gateway Church: Mike Bollinger</span> 
      Played: <div class="plays">16</div> times</p>
</div>
```

... repeated for more audio files - 
A specific instance would be one of the particular audio element that was clicked. My code updates just the right one. My difficulty is the line

```
$($container,'.plays').html(response);
```

I can't work out how to just update the number of plays for that audio instance
How do I get it to work please?

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup please?

Comment: 'specific instance' ? explain more

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the id was for the audio tag and didn't cover the plays class. Modified the  to include the id

and then changed the html response line to 
    $('.plays'+fileID).html(response);